# Mimicking a click on a button inside an iframe. No errors, but no response

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is currently set up in this way:

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <iframe src="https://theurl.com"></iframe>
```

Within the iframe (which has no ID assigned), there are buttons set up like this:

```
<div class="tv-tabs__scroll-box">
  <div class="tv-tabs__tab js-timeframe-tab" data-timeframe="1d">1d</div>
  <div class="tv-tabs__tab js-timeframe-tab" data-timeframe="1m">1m</div>
  <div class="tv-tabs__tab js-timeframe-tab" data-timeframe="3m">3m</div>
</div>
```

The default option selected is not my desired selection, I want to be able to automatically have the script load the "1d" chart. Any clues on why my function isn't working?

```
jQuery(function($) { 
  $('.tradingview-widget-container > iframe').contents().find('[data-timeframe="1d"]').trigger("click")
});
```

I'm not getting an error, but the chart view is remaining the same. Do I need to set a POST request as well?

For reference, I am trying to implement this with this widget: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The iframe is showing cross-domain content. As such, you cannot affect it in any way from the parent. What you are attempting to do is not possible, for a variety of security reasons.

Comment: If you're married to the idea you could possibly find a solution, something like.. if the 3 buttons are the only elements that are clickable in the iframe, you could space them evenly in a row, then position an element over top of the iframe divided in 3 rows with 100% height and make those 3 rows clickable. It would of course be more complicated if the iframe needs to be scrolled, and if each iframe loads buttons that do things based on their id's or data= etc. I wouldn't think impossible but maybe not worth the effort to code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory McCrossan had said, the problem was not the JS query itself, but a security feature implemented by TradingView.